# How sum the listbox items

Tags: c#, listbox, windows-phone

I have a listbox with three values. I need get the `FEstado` value for all items of ListBox and sum them. However, this ListBox not have defined items, the user select items from another ListBox.

My Listbox:

```
<ListBox Name="List2" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Margin="0,43,-66,0">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Margin="0,0,0,17" Width="432" Height="95" Hold="holdListRmv">
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding FNome}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextExtraLargeStyle}"/>
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding FEstado}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="12,-6,12,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextSubtleStyle}"/>
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Text="{Binding Quantity}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="12,-6,12,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Comment: Are you using MVVM? why you dont sumarize the values on the View Model and then Bind where you want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you populate the `ListBox` by adding model item to `ListBox`'s `Items` property (as shown in [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25548021/windows-phone-listbox-hold-item-event)), then you can get all items from the same `ListBox.Items` property. And assuming that `FEstado` is a number, you can do something like this :

```
var items = List2.Items.Cast<Fields>();
var total = items.Sum(o => o.FEstado);
```

Comment: This code works for me. And again you saved me. Thank you very much my friend.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this,
try this:

XAML:

```
<Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="0">
    <StackPanel>
        <ListBox Name="List2" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Margin="0,43,-66,0">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Margin="0,0,0,17" Width="432" Height="95" >
                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding FNome}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextExtraLargeStyle}"/>
                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding FEstado}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="12,-6,12,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextSubtleStyle}"/>
                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Text="{Binding Quantity}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="12,-6,12,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
        <Button Content="sum" Click="Button_Click_1"></Button>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

cs:

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
    ObservableCollection<DataClass> obj = new ObservableCollection<DataClass>();
    obj.Add(new DataClass("AA", "10", "10"));
    obj.Add(new DataClass("BB", "10", "10"));
    List2.ItemsSource = obj;
}

private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < List2.Items.Count; i++)
    {
        DataClass obj = (DataClass)List2.Items[i];
        sum += int.Parse(obj.FEstado.ToString());
    }
    MessageBox.Show(sum.ToString());
}

public class DataClass
{
    public string FNome { get; set; }
    public string FEstado { get; set; }
    public string Quantity { get; set; }
    public DataClass() { }

    public DataClass(string FNome, string FEstado, string Quantity)
    {
        this.FNome = FNome;
        this.FEstado = FEstado;
        this.Quantity = Quantity;
    }
}
```